# SQL Server 2012 Ansi Warnings and SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

When the query or stored procedure is run form SSRS, the ANSI warnings are setting to OFF - the connection takes defaults values from Server properties.

Is there any way to determinate the ANSI warnings ON for current user (not for entire server) who is define in connections ?

SQL Server 2012

Comment: You can set the default on the server, or on the database, but not per user and not in the connection string. Per connection, you can issue a `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON` statement. I would still recommend setting the default to `ON`, at least on the database. Reason: very few applications actually *use* that default rather than setting it explicitly (with, apparently, SSRS as an exception), and you really *want* `ANSI_WARNINGS` to be `ON` anyway. The chance of another application breaking on this default is pretty small (though not zero).

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert many thanks, but when i define in SSRS connection string and properties, am I able to write SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON statement  ?

Comment: No, you cannot. It must be issued as a statement. I don't know if SSRS has hooks to do this for every connection/query.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand you. Many thanks again. Now I have to find the easiest way to change it in few hundred reports :).

Comment: Or you could, you know, change the default setting on the database level in a test environment and see if anything actually breaks. If you have fewer than a few hundred *applications*, this is undoubtedly faster. And more future proof to boot.

Comment: Ok, but I cannot do that. I'm thinking about, maybe trigger wich modify seesion properties before logon. I found some information about it and it's seems optimistic. I know users who use this so I can limit modified sessions ( but now it's only a theory )